# How can I split my Vue js project into development and test?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to divide my vuejs frontend project into two parts as development and test. In the development part, I want to work in my local and request the example:8010 urline, and in the test part, I want to send a request to the example:80 address. How can I do this, I did a source search but couldn't find anything.

Example of a request I wrote:

```
      var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', this.image[0]);
  await axios
    .post('example', formData, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6fdsaeqImNoZ3VuYXkzQGdtYWlsLmNvbqSIsImlkIjoxLCJ0eXBlIjoxLCJpYXQiOjE2NDU0NDUxMjR9.Kg8NcFiAKtBHxkQsRwl2pO6svp7SDQSQw13SJ4xe1vc`,
      },
    })

    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.id);

    
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: You need to get axios base url from environment variable.

Comment: I will do it for the first time, can you send an example or document? @EstusFlask

Answer (score 1):

Serkan

You can use .env files for your environments. You can add dotenv package your project, or you can give parameters inside of your scripts part of you package.json

[here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html) you can follow this page to use your env variables inside vue app. Keep in mind you must start VUE_APP for your variables:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_API = 'yourapplink/api'
```

You should create 2 .env files 1 for your local development other for your production and you can add as much as you like.

You can create .env.development and put your variables in it then start your vue app with:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode development
```

And you should see app using your .env.development file.

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer. So, when I deploy the test environment on heroku, how can I get heroku to run vue-cli-service build --mode as test? do you know?

Comment: You should not build in heroku you should put built version of the app to heroku. You should build it in your local machine then it will build in builds folder etc. You should put these files to heroku or another static web page server like s3 etc. If it was correct can you mark as answer?